# changing node shape in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I need nodes in different shapes in NetworkX, some rectangle and triangle nodes. Does anybody know if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, there is a property node_shape that allows changing shape.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the node shape using `add_nodes_from`
I tried:
`B.add_nodes_from(daraframe.index, bipartite=0,  color = 'green', node_shape = "s")`